# Solve $y'/y^2 = (1-2x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

If we separate the differential equation $y'/y^2 = (1-2x)$ with the assumption that $y(1) = \frac{-1}{6}$, we obtain $y = \frac{1}{(x-3)(x+2)}$.  The solution of this problem in my textbook claims that this is a valid solution only for $-2 < x < 3$.  Why can't it be a solution everywhere except $-2$ and $3$?

Comment: The standard assumption for the solutions of a Cauchy problem is that their domain is an interval containing $t_0$ (in this case $t_0=1$) and that they are continuous (actually, differentiable).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the initial condition $y(1) = -1/6$ doesn't say *anything* about what happens outside the interval $(-2, 3)$. You would need new initial conditions for both the interval $(\infty, -2)$ and for $(3, \infty)$.

Comment: So $y = \frac{1}{(x-3)(x-2)}$, as defined on $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{-2,3\}$, is a particular solution of that differential equation with the specified conditions, but the general solution would be defined piecewise (unique in the interval $(-2,3)$ but not unique everywhere).  Or to make things simpler we can just assume the domain of the solution is an open interval.

Comment: @D_S Well, you _can't_ solve it for $x \in \Bbb R\setminus[-2, 3]$, simply because there are infinitely many solutions. Now, you can find the general form of such solutions, and if you were given an initial condition, you could find what would be a solution, but until then, the only place where you can solve the equation, and find _the_ solution, is on $(-2, 3)$.

Answer (score 0):

In the solution of differential equations particular solutions are obtained for particulary chosen initial/boundary conditions. That solution is valid only for those chosen conditions set out, and apart from the general case. If you want it outside the limits the only way is to choose a suitable new initial point.